# lein cljsbuild fails with untraceable error. How do you troubleshoot cljsbuild errors?

Tags: clojurescript, cljsbuild

I do not see any log file for the compilation and the error in the terminal is insufficient for me to troubleshoot further.
How do i get more verbose error logging or how should i trouble shoot this issue?

First few lines from stacktrace below

```
Compiling ClojureScript...
Compiling ["resources/public/js/app.js"] from ["src/cljs"]...
Compiling ["resources/public/js/app.js"] failed.
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: failed compiling file:resources\public\js\out\cljs\core.cljs {:file #object[java.io.File 0x7c5d1d25 "resources\\public\\js\\out\\cljs\\core.cljs"], :clojure.error/phase :compilation}
        at cljs.compiler$compile_file$fn__3901.invoke(compiler.cljc:1706)
        at cljs.compiler$compile_file.invokeStatic(compiler.cljc:1666)
```

I have a simple cljs file with the following contents

```
(ns moose.core)   
(defn run []
  (.write js/document "This is not the end!"))
```

My project.clj has the following config for cljsbuild

```
:cljsbuild
  {:builds [{:id           "dev"
             :source-paths ["src/cljs"]
             :figwheel {:on-jsload "moose.core/run"
                        :open-urls ["http://localhost:3449/index.html"]}
             :jar true
             :compiler     {:main moose.core 
                            :warnings true
                            :output-dir "resources/public/js/out" 
                            :asset-path "js/out"
                            :output-to "resources/public/js/app.js"}}]}
  :clean-targets ^{:protect false} [:target-path :compile-path "resources/public/js" "dev-target"]
```

**Update 1**
Following Alan's advice below, i created a new template and narrowed down the cause to adding a fairly old library for interacting with CouchDB

[[com.ashafa/clutch "0.4.0"]](https://github.com/clojure-clutch/clutch)

The question remains how do I get detailed/complete logs for cljsbuild.

**Update 2**
Turns out the position of the library in the list of dependencies has an impact.
If it appears before  [[com.cognitect/transit-clj "0.8.313"]](https://github.com/cognitect/transit-clj) compilation fails otherwise it works.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if cljsbuild produces more information for this failure with ClojureScript 1.10.439 and earlier. (ClojureScript 1.10.516 introduced a change to exception messages.) If so, perhaps a ticket against cljsbuild could be written to have it updated for 1.10.516.

Comment: @MikeFikes I tried 238,439,516 and 520 got the same error message but different callsites and just this additional piece of information ":clojure.error/phase :compilation"

Answer (score 1):

The configuration options in ClojureScript are not well documented.  It is easiest to clone an existing (working) project and go from there.  I would suggest starting from [the cljs-template project](https://github.com/cloojure/cljs-template) as follows (see the README):

```
git clone  https://github.com/cloojure/cljs-template.git  demo-0212  ; temp 

> cd demo-0212 
~/expr/demo-0212 > ls -ldF *
-rwxrwxr-x 1 alan alan  222 Feb 12 16:04 npm-install.bash*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 alan alan 4216 Feb 12 16:04 project.clj*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan 1576 Feb 12 16:04 README.adoc
drwxrwxr-x 3 alan alan 4096 Feb 12 16:04 resources/
drwxrwxr-x 5 alan alan 4096 Feb 12 16:04 src/
drwxrwxr-x 4 alan alan 4096 Feb 12 16:04 test/

~/expr/demo-0212 > ./npm-install.bash 
...<snip>... lots of stuff
```

At this point your project has the npm stuff needed for the unit tests.

```
> lein clean
> lein doo phantom test once

;; ======================================================================
;; Testing with Phantom:

doorunner - beginning
doorunner - end

Testing tst.flintstones.dino
test once - enter
globalObject:   #js {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3}
(-> % .-b (+ 5) => 7
(js/makeDino) => #js {:desc blue dino-dog, :says #object[Function]}
dino.desc =>  blue dino-dog
dino.says(5) =>  Ruff-Ruff-Ruff-Ruff-Ruff!
:keep-words ("am" "having" "today")
:re-seq ("am" "having" "today")
test once - leave

Testing tst.flintstones.wilma
test each - enter
test each - leave
test each - enter
wilmaPhony/stats:    #js {:lipstick red, :height 5.5}
wilma => #js {:desc patient housewife, :says #object[Function]}
test each - leave

Testing tst.flintstones.pebbles
test once - enter
test once - leave

Testing tst.flintstones.slate
logr-slate-enter
logr-slate-leave 3

Testing tst.flintstones.bambam
test each - enter
test each - leave
test each - enter
logr-bambam-enter
logr-bambam-leave 3
test each - leave

Ran 9 tests containing 22 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
lein doo phantom test once  38.73s user 1.05s system 313% cpu 12.701 total
```

You can also fire off figwheel to see results in the browser:

```
> lein clean
> lein figwheel

see new webpage (30-60 sec delay)

------------------------
Figwheel template
Checkout your developer console.

I am a component!

I have bold and red text.
...etc...
------------------------
```

Comment: Very true but it is discomforting to not know why compilation failed when there is practically nothing to compile.